# How to do property search using rets XML with PHP

Tags: php, xml, rets

I have RETS configured and downloaded complete data on my live server. I want someone helps to figure me out how to do search data from the RETSdata.

Suppose, from the search form I choose, 2 beds, price ranges 100000 and 3 bath rooms. Now, I want to query this data from RETS XML and show the results based on this search criteria.

Can anybody give me direction. I have all the XML data saved on the server. Now I want to query the data based on the search criteria i will post on XML file.

Comment: do you think rets data search can be done using above url?

Comment: I am not sure I would download the raw XML. I would use something like [PHPRETS](https://github.com/troydavisson/PHRETS) to make ad-hoc queries against a live RETS server. Then save those results local or just use the data returned and display it to the user.

Comment: @dj_goku can you provide any working code or link in order to get those response data?

Comment: Your code in this other [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28279504/phrets-is-not-searching-the-data) seems to be valid. But I haven't ever used PHPRETS before so I can't say 100%.

Comment: What MLS are you using?

Answer (score 0):

This answer is old, but might help someone who comes back here looking for the answer.

Just import the XML into a database (MySQL maybe?), and query the database. That's usually the 'standard' why of ETL (extract-transform-load) RETS data, to later query it.